# Kubuntu 15.10, pager appears twice

Tags: kde, desktop, pager, kde5

The desktop switcher on my taskbar appears twice, once on the left side, once on the right. Also I cannot position it anywhere I like. Does anyone know how I can delete one of the desktop switchers and move the other one in another place on the taskbar?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: right click on taskbar => Panel Options => Panel Settings, then just go over the widgets and click the X to remove them.

Comment: to move, instead of clicking the X, click and drag your applet. Previous to any of this, right click on the taskbar and Unlock Widgets.